# iPhone . stringWithCString encoding

Tags: iphone

I am compiling a code segment using something like this:

```
char* filename = (char*) malloc( fileInfo.size_filename +1 );
unzGetCurrentFileInfo(_unzFile, &fileInfo, filename, fileInfo.size_filename + 1, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
filename[fileInfo.size_filename] = '\0';

NSString * strPath = [NSString  stringWithCString:filename];
```

but stringWithCString is deprecated. I am supposed to change that to

```
NSString * strPath = [NSString  stringWithCString:filename encoding:????];
```

this filename as the name says represents entries on the file system, files and directories. How do I know the encoding filename is using? I mean, I can put UTF-8, but who knows which encoding users around the world will be using. If I choose any encoding I will be limiting that.

How do I solve that to put the correct encoding for each user.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, for C paths, you want something a bit uglier:

```
NSString *strPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] stringWithFileSystemRepresentation:filename length:strlen(filename)];
```

And to go the other way:

```
const char *cPath = [nsFilename fileSystemRepresentation];
```